# Getting posts by tag instagram - 404

Tags: tags, instagram, instagram-api

Below is my current code to get the latest instagram pics.

```
 getInstagram:function(num_photos) {
        var token = 'xxxxxx',

      userid = xxxxxxxx,
      num_photos = num_photos; // how much photos do you want to get


         var x;
         var instapics = [];
         var instalink = [];
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + userid + '/media/recent', 
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
          success: function(data){
            for( x in data.data ){
             instalink.push(data.data[x].link);
             instapics.push(data.data[x].images.standard_resolution.url);

            }


        var index = 0;
        var holders = $('.grid .instagram-holder');
        $(holders).each(function() {
          $(this).html('<img src='+instapics[index]+' />').wrap("<a href="+instalink[0]+"></a>");;
            index++;
        });

      },
      error: function(data){

      }
    });

           },
```

I now want to get them by tag 'people', I have added the endpoint

```
 url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/people/media/recent',
```

and

```
 url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/people/media/recent?access_token='+token
```

but get a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is working fine for me with a proper access token. Can you show us what instagram is actually returning?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting a 404 and not a 403?

You probably only have the `basic` permission. You'll need the `public_content` permission for that endpoint.